# Bochner Integral: Lebesgue Point

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

*This thread is just a note.*

Given an euclidean space and a Banach space.

Consider Bochner integrable functions:
$$F\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d,E):\quad\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\lambda<\infty$$

Then almost every point is a Lebesgue point:
$$D_r(F;z):=\frac{1}{\lambda(B_r(z))}\int_{B_r(z)}F\mathrm{d}\lambda=F(z)$$
How to obtain this from Lebesgue's version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is taken from Bochner's original paper.*

By strong measurability there are simple functions:
$$S_n\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,E):\quad S_n\to F$$

So one can decompose the above into:
$$\|D_r(F;z)-F(z)\|\leq D_r(\|F-S_N\|;z)+\|D_r(S_n;z)-S_N(z)\|+\|F(z)-S_N(z)\|$$

By linearity the second term reduces to:
$$D(a\chi_A+b\chi_B;z)=aD(\chi_A;z)+bD(\chi_B;z)$$

So the first and second term can be handled by Lebesgue's version.